# Selenium Message: unknown error: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to a very simple selenium line of code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

current_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
driver.get(current_url)
print(driver.page_source)
```

However I keep getting error that I do not understand what to do with. I can manually lauch chrome and open youtube, but when I run code I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Programming\WebScraping\Selenium\testing_selenium\testing1.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver.get(current_url)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 436, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99)
```

If anyone has any suggestion on how to deal with this, please share them here. I am not even completely sure what this error means. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Run without setting any options and see if that clears up the error.   Also let us know if you are running Selenium 3 or 4.  The error seems like it's related to the overall internet connection though... winsock or DNS error maybe?

Comment: selenium 4.1. I ran it without options and it worked on youtube, however I then tried another website and it does not work. same error. Can you give a little bit more info on winsock and DNS error? Also, I can acess everything using scrapy, it just does not load javascript.

Comment: It does seem that there is another error there. [10044:12192:0203/124305.573:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(871)] connect failed: 10051               what can be a solution for that? and is this a winsocket error

Comment: it's possible this is specific to Selenium 4.  I think it uses sockets to connect to the browser's debugging tools.  There should be a way to turn that off in chromeoptions, but not too sure.

Comment: I did indeed try it with latest version of Selenium 3.14, however it runs into the same error.

Comment: not sure what would be causing that... just as a shot in the dark try adding this: options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")

Comment: thanks a lot for answers though. helped to narrow things down. it turned out to be a program blocking webdriver from functioning properly.